# iOS Swift - how can access it in local storage after retrieving a JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I'm new to Swift and try to use it for my project.
I face a problem after retrieving the JSON data.

I know how to parse the JSON with `SwiftyJSON`, but now I decided to access it without connecting to the internet every time (using a cache) and store it in local storage.

But how do I save the data into local storage in an iOS Application?
Also, how to implement the flow?

I searched the documentation and it recommends using Core Data or NSCache
However, it is still confusing me at all.

Thanks

Comment: I think using coredata is bestway to storedata. here is one example http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_Core_Data_Tutorial

Comment: okay,i will take your suggestion.
btw,do have some json to coredata exmaple?